# Using own OAUTH2.0 authentication backend server with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am looking into Azure AD to use for identity management. I am trying to create a system where I can tie a user with different accounts (FB, Twt, etc.). We have our own authentication back end that supports OAUTH2.0 with users already, I have to use that backend to authenticate users. Is it possible to use Azure AD with my own authentication backend?

EDIT:
Apologies, I re-read the question and I realized I did not explain correctly. I need Azure AD to be responsible for authentication with my backend. I have a backend that supports OAUTH2.0, I would like to have azure AD be the middle man between my users and my authentication back-end (via OAUTH2.0).

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understand the nature of your question - namely to make **your** backend responsible for **Azure AD** authentication. If this is the case - then, no you cannot use Azure in that way.

However, you **can** use Azure AD as one more authentication option for your users (like FB, Twt, etc.). The keyword is Azure AD Multi Tenant App. Check out [this sample](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet). Multi tenant app you will need if you want to let **any** Office 365 (or Azure) subscriber access your application. If you want only **your own** Azure AD users to access your application, than you need simply [WebApp with OpenID Connect](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet) (based on OAuth) or just a [Web App](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-RoleClaims-DotNet).

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment, the following good articles are for you:

- [OAuth 2.0 in Azure AD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645545.aspx)
- [OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 support in Azure AD is GA](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/09/09/openid-connect-and-oauth-2-0-support-in-azure-active-directory-has-ga-d.aspx).

There are also some samples [here](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OAuth2-UserIdentity-DotNet) and there.

Comment: Apologies, I re-read the question and I realized I did not explain correctly. I am trying to do the opposite actually. I need Azure AD to be responsible for authentication with my backend. I have a backend that supports OAUTH2.0, I would like to have azure AD be the middle man between my users and my authentication back-end (via OAUTH2.0).

Comment: Unless I am understanding all the literature wrong, Azure AD does not seem to have the support for what I want. I see that Azure can support being between my user and my application and it can handle authentication for the user all on Azure side. I am attempting to have the following flow:

User loads app, clicks the log in button. A pop-up comes up say from moreno-backend.com to have the user enter credentials, upon successful authentication, have my back-end send the access-token to Azure AD, so I can then and only then create a user in Azure AD. I think my test case is very specific

Comment: So you only want AAD to serve as the data storage for your users, but you will take care of authentication? Or do you intend on passing the credentials that the user provides, and forwarding that to AAD for authentication?

Comment: @ Philippe Signoret - I will take care of authentication. I have to because I need the tokens, I am basically building a hybrid between authentication and authorization. I want to be able to handle the authorization part and get the tokens and then pass the tokens to Azure to have it link the user accounts for data syncing. AWS Cognito like behavior but using custom authorization/authentication backends